# An array mapping function in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this chunk of javascript code:

```
function arrayMapper(mappingFunc) {
  return items => items.map(mappingFunc);
}

function fooTransformer(tem) {
  return (...); // do something with item and returns a value
}

function barTransformer(tem) {
  return (...); // do something with item and returns a value
}

const foosTransformer = arrayMapper(fooTransformer);
const barsTransformer = arrayMapper(barTransformer);
(...)
foosTransformer([1, 2, 3]);
```

I was wondering if something like my `arrayMapper` function would exist natively in something like lodash, just to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: did you search the docs of lodash?

Comment: Yes, of course, but didn't found anything

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? It's a one-line function! Am I missing something?

Comment: Your `arrayMapper` function is just a wrapper for the native `Array.prototype.map` function, so what's even the point of it?

Comment: Ok, maybe it's over-engineered and I don't even need the `arrayMapper` function, I could use : `const foosTransformer = items => items.map(fooTransformer);` directly... 
it's just that I have 5 or 6 functions like that.

Comment: Or just run `[1, 2, 3].map(fooTransformer)` instead of creating that `foosTransformer` wrapper function first...

Comment: I use those array transformers in some unit tests as arguments of other functions according to a more functional programming spirit.

Comment: Regardless of whether it would be worth making this function or not, this question is off topic because it is essentially asking for recommendations for software.

Answer (score 2):

What you're essentially doing is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the map function (from the right).

Lodash allows you do to just that:

```js
const mapper = _.curryRight(_.map);

const square = mapper(x => x ** 2);

console.log(
  square([1, 2, 3]) // [1, 4, 9]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

That being said, it's certainly an overkill to bring in a whole library for such a small feature. Maybe if you're using npm, you could just `npm install lodash.curryright lodash.map` and use only those but that's still likely to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `chain` method and then you can add `map` multiple times and at the end call `value()`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var add1 = e => e + 1;
var add2 = e => e + 2;

var result = _.chain(arr).map(add1).map(add2).value()
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use ES6 parameter destructuring and `reduce()` to create function that takes array and any number of callback function and call map method on that array with each function you provided.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var add1 = e => e + 1;
var add2 = e => e + 2;

function arrayMapper(arr, ...mappingFunc) {
  return mappingFunc.reduce((r, f) => (r = Array.prototype.map.call(r, f), r), arr)
}


var result = arrayMapper(arr, add1, add2)
console.log(result)
```